# Kotlin - function composition - explanation

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, function-composition

I am following some video [presentation](http://youtu.be/tM2wEI-e80E?t=157) on Kotlin's arrow library about functional programming. I have come to this example of function composition:

```
val greaterThanThree = { it > 3 } 
val even = { it % 2 == 0 }
val greaterThanThreeAndEven = greaterThanThree compose even
```

then it can be used for something like:

```
list.filter(::greaterThanThreeAndEven)
```

From my previous understanding of function composition is that the we pass the paramater to the first function then returned value is passed to the second function, like in this example:

```
fun compose(f: (Int) -> Boolean, g: (Int) -> Boolean): (Int) -> Boolean = {
                                                                   x -> f(g(x)) }
```

So, I don't know if I got this right, since I haven't been dealing with functional programming yet, but I thought the steps would be something like this:

> val x = 8 is passed to greaterThanThree(8)  evaluates to -> true
> // then the confusing part for me is that according to the logic above true would be passed to even which makes no sense
>
> even(true)

Can somebody explain me how are this two functions composed and what are the steps for this resulting composed function:

```
{ it > 3 && it % 2 == 0 }
```

Comment: Can you link to the source? I don't know Kotlin but that doesn't look like any kind of function composition I ever saw....

Comment: @JaredSmith this is the video tutorial on arrow library where greaterThanThree and even example is shown, example starts here: https://youtu.be/tM2wEI-e80E?t=157

Comment: Yeah, that's... different? Assuming those are functions you are correct that something is wrong, depending on how Kotlin treats bools (in some languages they are a subclass of int) that either shouldn't compile (type mismatch) or will compile but give wrong answers.

Comment: does this code compile without any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compose` is not `&&`, it's nested function calls.

In the body of your function definition

```
fun compose(f: (Int) -> Boolean, g: (Int) -> Boolean): (Int) -> Boolean = { x -> f(g(x)) }
```

`g` is called with parameter `x` so that `x` should be an `Int` and the `g(x)` returns a `Boolean`.

However, `f` is called with the return value of `g` as the parameter.
Since `f` requires an `Int` and `g` returns a `Boolean`, the compiler reports error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean but Int was expected
```

If you want to compose boolean functions, this may be an example,

```
fun booleanCompose(
    f: (Int) -> Boolean,
    g: (Int) -> Boolean,
    op: (Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean,
): (Int) -> Boolean = {
    x -> op(f(x), g(x))
}

val greaterThanThree: (Int) -> Boolean = { it > 3 }
val even: (Int) -> Boolean = { it %2 == 0 }

val and: (Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean = { b1, b2 -> b1 && b2 }

val greaterThanThreeAndEven = booleanCompose(greaterThanThree, even, and)
```

To allow the syntax you used, an extension infix function is needed:

```
infix fun ((Int) -> Boolean).and(g: (Int) -> Boolean): (Int) -> Boolean = 
    booleanCompose(this, g, and)

val greaterThanThreeAndEven = greaterThanThree and even
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks right, I was really confused with that example from arrow tutorial, it is so weird that they are using examples that can't even compile, 'cos it is easy to confuse noobies like me with such wrong examples.

Comment: @Leff I definitely don't consider myself a newbie at FP, and it confused me. I think it's just plain confusing lol.

Comment: @JaredSmith that is comforting